# jQuery/Angular - Sticky sidebar is not respecting the full height of a the corresponding div (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

going to the point, [look at my Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/opWJn6g43cfxRhZ8J5xR?p=preview)

**please expand the view window on Plunkr to check it.**

there is a div with a class named `.border`, which is the class giving the red border, if you see the example, you can scroll down and scroll down and the window will be increasing his size, before that wasn't happening until I decided to do it sticky. Now you can scroll and the window, as I mention before, is just increasing his size.

And also I can not set up a fixed size for the div including the red border because sometimes that size will dynamically change depending on what data you are loading.

All I want is that the sticky sidebar do not go beyond the red border.

this is the jQuery code that I am pretty sure that here is where I am failing:

```
$(function() {
  var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
  var topPadding = 85;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
      $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
      });
    } else {
      $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
        marginTop: 50
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I am also doing the same but with AngularJS and is happening exactly the same, you can check the AngularJS code here:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('sticky', function($document, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          var offset = element.offset(),
              topPadding = 55;
          $document.scroll(function() {

            if ($document.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
              console.log($document.scrollTop());
              console.log(offset.top);
              element.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $document.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
              });
            } else {
              offset.top;
              element.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }, 350);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Does this help? http://plnkr.co/edit/H5fWCaxSN6bvnCiW4Fi2?p=preview

Comment: @RonGilchrist actually has the same behavior, what I want to correct is that when you reach the bottom, if you scroll down once again nothing must happen. Try it yourself my friend: scroll at the bottom and then go ahead and do it again, you will that the window will be increasing his size, that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: The behavior should be turned off in single-column mode, yes? It is no longer a sidebar at this point, but a top-bar. When I resize the  page area wide enough with my plunk, the bug does not exist.

Comment: @RonGilchrist yes, but I need to correct on every sizes.